# Using LINQ Lambda expression determining value by group by and where condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So I have the following data table:

```
Region      Class
Reg100      A
Reg100      B
Reg200      A
Reg300      B
```

Where I want to determine a region that has two classes A and B. In this case it would be Reg100. How could I write this in using lambda expression?

I have tried something like below but not getting what I want.

```
dt.Where(x => x.Class.Contains(listOfAandB).GroupBy(x=>x.Region).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define the input:

```
class Data
{
    public string Region;
    public string Class;
}

var dt = new[] 
{ 
    new Data { Region = "Reg100", Class = "A" },
    new Data { Region = "Reg100", Class = "B" },
    new Data { Region = "Reg200", Class = "A" },
    new Data { Region = "Reg300", Class = "B" },
};
```

Now, using `GroupBy` we can group the input by Region.

```
dt.GroupBy(x => x.Region)
```

This yields { Reg100 (A, B), Reg200 A, Reg 300 B }. Now we look if we can find both A and B:

```
dt.GroupBy(x => x.Region)
    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Class == "A") && g.Any(x => x.Class == "B"))
```

And finally as we are only interested in the region, we project to it:

```
dt.GroupBy(x => x.Region)
    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Class == "A") && g.Any(x => x.Class == "B"))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```